# Implement Wurfl

Tags: .net, mobile, wurfl

I am just starting out with Wurfl implementation for a ASP.NET web site. Could someone please provide me some directions for any available documentation.

Thank you,

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [51deegres](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/) framework, you can find examples in this page. If you want to study other code, you could look at [Marg.WURFL](http://www.mihavalencic.com/?pagename=WurflApi) too. I used a modification of it in the past, but now I use 51degrees.

Comment: 51Degrees.mobi hasn't used WURFL data since December 2011. It uses device data sourced and maintained by our own professional team. Easiest way to install is via NuGet. Documentation on the web site. James (Founder of 51Degrees.mobi)

Answer (score 3):

Luca Passani (WURFL Creator and ScientiamObile's CTO) here.

You should use ScientiaMobile's own standard WURFL .NET API:

http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/dotNet/

NuGet: http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/WURFL_Official_API

This the true and only WURFL dotNet API created specifically to work with the WURFL repository (also delivered by ScientiaMobile). To add to that, third-party APIs can no longer access the wurfl repository legally (unless the repository is licensed commercially from ScientiaMobile itself).

Thank you

Luca Passani